# Laravel join query is showing wrong results

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 tables `clinics` , `locations` , `services`  & `location_services` in which relations are clinicid is present in locations and both serviceid and location id is present in location_services table.

My requirement is that i want to retrive all the cinics and their coreesponding locations and services .

But when i tried it is retrving the results of only one clinic id , i dont know how can i retrive complete list

following is my code

```
 $clinic = Clinic::find($id);
        $locations = Location::where('clinicID', $id)->get();
        $locationservices = Service::select('services.serviceName as servicename','locations.locationID as locid','locations.locationName as locname') 
        ->join('location_services', 'location_services.serviceID', '=', 'services.serviceID')
        ->join('locations', 'locations.locationID', '=', 'location_services.locationID') 
        ->join('clinics', 'clinics.clinicID', '=', 'locations.clinicID') 
        ->where('clinics.clinicID','=',$id) 
        ->toSql();
        dd($locationservices);
        die();
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: You ma use `hasManyThrough` relationship. [https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through]

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

Comment: This is not eloqunet method